# Can NSsliderCell work in "continuous" mode when inside a TableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

Is it possible for a NSSliderCell to work in "continuous" mode when inside a cell-based NSTableView? I've searched here on S.O. and also googled the question without seeing anything directly relevant.

In Interface Builder I have checked the "continuous' properties for both the Slidercell and the TableView, but I cannot get the slider to send out continuous messages.

I have no problem using NSSlider controls in continuous mode elsewhere in my application,  and the Slidercell/Tableview in question here works fine as is, but updates only when the mouse is released.

Is it necessary to use a View-based Tableview to get this behaviour? I would rather not do that because it means a messy rewrite of the code for several other tableviews as well.

(edit)
The below code is in VFX Forth, using their provided Cocoa bridge.            The relevant portion in tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:  is :

" BPAd" theid$ @isEqualToString: 
       ?of    objectid @floatValue 
                phr# paraatom# PHRASE.ATOM#>A +atomExtra 04 + SF!
        endof

" BPad" is the identifier for the column containing the slider cell.
'The next line just takes the floatValue from the slider and stores in into my data-structure. 
The above all works exactly as expected, but ONLY on release of the mouse-button. It does not act continuously.

thanks in advance for any insight

Comment: Hi bgdegazio, ist your table view a dynamic or a static table view?

Comment: Yes, `NSSliderCell` can work in "continuous" mode when inside a cell-based `NSTableView`. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: MacUserT -- the TableView in question is dynamic. It uses a data source object to dynamically update its cells.

Comment: Willeke - Thanks for the assurance that NSSliderCell can work in continuous mode.

Comment: By the way cell-based NSTableView is outdated for many, many years.

Comment: See [continuous](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428952-continuous?language=occ). "A Boolean value indicating whether the cell sends its action message continuously during mouse tracking.". Connect the slider to an action method.